# mp4fragment reduces video file duration

Tags: media, mp4, transcoding, bento4

Trying to create fragmented MP4 file from a non-fragmented one via command

```
mp4fragment --fragment-duration 10000 5ca31321e4b068348e2220a9-480p.mp4 5ca31321e4b068348e2220a9-480p.mp4_fragmented
```

But got media with incorrect duration of **2880000** ms (~ 48 minutes)

```
mediainfo --Inform=file:///var/cache/tomcat/temp/SC2024943881495774878TMP 5ca31321e4b068348e2220a9-480p.mp4_fragmented 
CompleteName=5ca31321e4b068348e2220a9-480p.mp4_fragmented
```

> Duration=2880000
>   Width=848
>   Height=480
>   BitRate=1099968
>   VideoId=1
>   AspectRatio=1.767
>   Language_3=

The original media file duration is **2880040**:

```
mediainfo --Inform=file:///var/cache/tomcat/temp/SC2024943881495774878TMP 5ca31321e4b068348e2220a9-480p.mp4
```

> Duration=2880040
>   Width=640
>   Height=360
>   BitRate=800000
>   VideoId=1
>   AspectRatio=1.778
>   Language_3=

Comment: Is there an audio track? What is its duration? Also what is time base of the video track? Did mp4fragment modify it? is it a multiple of the frame rate? If not, it may just be a rounding error as 40ms is only about one frame.

Comment: @szatmary, 1) yes, video has audio, 2) I guess a duration of audio is the same as duration of video, 3) could you please describe what a time base is, 4) yes, mp4fragment modified the original video

Comment: 2) that is statically VERY unlikely as audio frame durations are not usually multiples of video frames. So there is almost certainly a delta 3) it’s how time is measured in video file. Mp4 uses a (implies) frame number multiplied by a time base ratio. Time stamps can not be more accurate than its time base. 3) I mean was the time base modified? I understand the file was modified. All of this information is required to answer the question. This is a math question, and we are missing at least 5 variables (Audio duration and time base numerator and denominator for source and destination)